# Get SQLAlchemy return type as Dict

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I was trying to get some details from SQLAlchemy table.

Consider there is invoice exists for different tenants, I need to fetch the invoice details for each tenant.

Have framed the API code for the same.

See the code which acts as the heart of the above mentioned scenario.

```
def get_invoice(self):

    model = models.InvoiceDetails
    session = db.get_session()

    # Query the Table for all invoice
    q = session.query(model).order_by(model.id)

    n = {}

    r = q.all()

    for m in r:

            g = m.__dict__

            tenant_id = m.__dict__['tenant_id']

            n[tenant_id] = g

    return n
```

I am trying to fetch the returned values. Value which is returned is as follows:

```
{u'b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97': {'balance_cost': None, 'invoice_id': u'tenant_for_test-1-2016', '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f608b7ed510>, 'id': 2}, u'7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829': {'balance_cost': None, 'invoice_id': u'demo-1-2016', '_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f608b7ed550>, 'id': 1}}
```

That is above code returned the results as above, That is two invoice entries from the table.

Then here I need to go through the results and fetched the needed results by using the tenant ID key(u'b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97', u'7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829')

But as it is unicode I am unable to do so.

Type of the same is as follows:

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

So My question is how to get the invoice_dict based on the tenant_id key(u'b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97', u'7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829').

When I was trying to get it shows error as follows:

```
    print invoice['tenant_id']
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Then also need to eliminate `'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f608b7ed510>` from the return value.

Someone assist me regarding the same.

Please comment if it is not clear or not making sense.

**Note:**

When I am trying to print n in the code it is fine, It is actually a dict.

But when I am trying to fetch the data using API from outside.

Result is simply a unicode.

**Edit:**

invoiceDetails definition:

```
mysql> desc invoice_details;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| invoice_date        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_period_from | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_period_to   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tenant_id           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_id          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| invoice_data        | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tenant_name         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total_cost          | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| paid_cost           | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| balance_cost        | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_status      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can you show your `InvoiceDetails` definition?

Comment: @Антонио-Антуан Please check the edit now

Comment: Please comment if you giving negative vote , So that I can know what is wrong there

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have the answer for your question, bur at first there are several advices :)

1. You can not to use `r = q.all()`, because it creates a new unnecessary variable. Just use that version:

   `for row in q:
   ...`
2. Also, `q` is unnecessary too. You can define your query in your cicle, like this:

   `for row in session.query(model).filter(...):...`
3. You can use `_asdict()`method of every row to get instead of `__dict__`. There will be only attributes of the result, without `_sa_*` attributes
4. You can get any attribute of a `row` without using dictionary syntax, like this:

   `tenant_id = row. tenant_id`
5. Well, and the answer. You can use dict compehensions:

   `result = {r.tenant_id: r._asdict() for r in q}`

And, as i say, you can not to use dict, so, `_asdict()` is unnecessary.

This is it. Does it work?

Comment: Thank u for help.. But now am getting an error as follows:
AttributeError: 'InvoiceDetails' object has no attribute '_asdict'

Comment: What is the version of sqlachemy do you use?

Comment: I am using  SQLAlchemy-1.0.12

Comment: My fault, the method is available only for non-model row-result. Do you really need the dict object? You can call attributes with dot: `result['b77865b66fd544e0841aa7dbca8bdc97'].tenant_name`

Comment: Sorry, Badly I need a Dict itself.
Will check thank u for your time.